# Function in matlab guide to check for invalid values

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am writing a function for my Matlab guide programme. I want to apply a limit for 3 text boxes in guide from 0 to 1 and it should only be number. (if a user inputs values that are invalid an error box should generate).The problem is that I want to write one function for that instead of writing limit code in the call back of each text box. It is also not necessary for the user to enter all the values at once, rather the function should run when any of the three values are input by the user and generate feedback. The function that I have written is as follows but it is not working. (It is not necessary that all the three input are provided to a function that's why I used || between inputs)

```
function CheckMe(maxMBT || minMBT || mainMBT)

 max_MBT= str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));

if isnan(maxMBT)||maxMBT < 0|| maxMBT> 1

  errordlg('Invalid max value for MBT. Please enter values between 0 to 1');
set(max_MBT, 'String', 0);

if isnan(minMBT)||minMBT < 0|| minMBT> 1
    set(min_MBT, 'String', 0);
    errordlg('Invalid min value for MBT. Please enter values between 0 to 1');

if isnan(mainMBT)||mainMBT < 0 || mainMBT >1
    set(edtMBT, 'String', 0);
    errordlg('Invalid value of MBT. Enter values between 0 to 1');

end
end
 end
```

Comment: You cannot define a function like this. The syntax is `function [out_args = ] <name>(arg1 [, arg2 [...]])`, with the bits between square brackets being optional. What you want to do is define a function that does the checking, and call that function from each of the three callback functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, optional arguments are not passed with `||` separating them. Instead, I'd recommend using 2 inputs:

1. Input the value you want to check
2. Input what 'type' of value this is, dependent on which callback is triggered.

The function would look something like this:

```
function valid = CheckMe( userInput, boxType )
% This checks for valid inputs between 0 and 1.
% USERINPUT should be a string from the input text box
% BOXTYPE should be a string specified by the callback, to identify the box

    % Do the check on the userInput value
    userInput = str2double( userInput );
    if isnan( userInput ) || userInput < 0 || userInput > 1
        % boxType specific error message
        errordlg(['Invalid value for ' boxType '. Please enter values between 0 to 1']);
        % Output flag
        valid = false;
    else
        valid = true;
    end           

end
```

This function returns a Boolean variable `valid`, which you can use in your callback function like so:

```
validatedInput = CheckMe( '0.5', 'TestBox' ); % Using the function to check input
if ~validatedInput
    % Input wasn't valid!
    myTextBox.String = '0';
end
```

Comment: Please Wolfie help me to resolve this issue as I am a beginner

Comment: I have helped you by leaving an answer with code you can almost use directly in your project and comments on how it works... What more do you want? Looking at your deleted answers which should have been question edits, the error is quite clear- what is `MBT` supposed to be?

Comment: it is supposed to be string. Yes you have really explained it very well. I tried doing it but its giving error. is thsi synta ok? boxType = set (handles.boxType, 'String', MBT)?

Comment: Nope, you're trying to set `boxType` equal to the output of a `set` command, but the `set` command doesn't have an output... What are you trying to do on that line? I suspect you just want something like `boxType = get( handles.MyTextBox, 'String' )`, but then I don't know what `handles` is.

Comment: As you said " BOXTYPE should be a string specified by the callback, to identify the box" . I am just trying to save MBT as string so that it can be passed to the functin you have given. What shoudld I write then?

Comment: Let's say you're in the callback which handles when input box 1 changes, you would call the function like `validatedInput = CheckMe( get(hObject, 'String'), 'inputBox1' )`. Look at how `boxType` is used within the `CheckMe` function - it isn't really, just for the error message, so it can be anything you want to identify which text box has triggered the check function. You could later use it to make the check function specific to each input box.

Comment: Yeah. I have finally done it. It was giving error again that invalid MBT so I remove the second input and simplified the function by printing same error dialog msg for all text boxes:)  Thanks very much

Comment: Happy to help, I think with a little more debugging you'd work out how you want to use whatever `MBT` is, but glad the simpler solution worked.

Comment: Thanks really for your mentoring

Comment: I have just checked but the problem is that the error box is coming up even if the values are valid:(

Comment: Please read about how to [debug a MATLAB program](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html), step through line by line and test the conditions which cause an error message. You should be able to test with expected values and see exactly which `if` statements are triggered and when. When debugging, try checking each of the 3 conditions individually which we combine to flag an invalid value.

Comment: ok. I just wanted to ask that for all the three text boxes (whose values need to be checked), the value will be stored in a same variable userInput?

Comment: In my example code yes, the `userInput` is the string which comes from the value in the text box. If the value in `userInput` changes then the value in the text box does not change, unless you set it to something as I do in the code (`... = '0'`).

Comment: myTextBox.String = '0'. Is myTextBox = tag of the text box where user input value?

Comment: `myTextBox` is the text box object. As in the actual GUI component.